# Change ListView status when found new result

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

Could anybody help me I already spent about 2 hours just for fixing my problem with ListView

what I did is, if the text (from `lbloutputName.text`) found in ListView item, it will highlight and will show the status of **Processing...**

Here's my question. How I can change the status to **Done** if the `searchItem` found new text from my output logs?

Here's what I'm thinking but I don't know how to do it.

For example, if I found `STRING1` the status will be **Processing...** and it will highlight the item in the ListView and then if found new `STRING2`, `STRING1` status must change to **Done.** and then `STRING2` will be **Processing** again.

Here's the code:

```vb
Dim searchItem As String = lblOutputName.Text

For Each lvi As ListViewItem In LV.Items
    For Each lvisub As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In lvi.SubItems
        If lvisub.Text = searchItem Then
            lvi.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue
            lvi.ForeColor = Color.White
            lvi.SubItems.Add("Processing...")
            LV.Focus()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Here's my screenshot for my tool:

[image: this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search the [ListViewItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem?view=netcore-3.1) and [ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem?view=netcore-3.1) objects, use the [ListView.FindItemWithText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.finditemwithtext?view=netcore-3.1) method:

```vb
Dim lvi = LV.FindItemWithText(searchItem)
```

If you want to search the sub items only (as I understand from your code snippet) and return the first match, you can do instead:

```vb
Dim lvi = LV.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem).
    FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.SubItems.Cast(Of ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem).
    Skip(1).Any(Function(y) y.Text.ToLower = searchItem.ToLower))
```

<sup>**Note:** `ToLower` for case-insensitive search.</sup>

Back to your main issue, you need to find a way to identify the already processed items to set their new state (`Done`), and set the state (`Processing`) of the item that you get from the search query if any:

```vb
If lvi IsNot Nothing Then
    LV.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem).
    Where(Function(x) x IsNot lvi AndAlso x.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue).
    ToList().ForEach(Sub(x)
                         x.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
                         x.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText
                         x.SubItems(x.SubItems.Count - 1).Text = "Done..."
                     End Sub)

    lvi.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue
    lvi.ForeColor = Color.White
    lvi.SubItems(lvi.SubItems.Count - 1).Text = "Processing..."
End If
```

You can use the `Tag` property instead to identify the processed items.

```vb
If lvi IsNot Nothing Then
    LV.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem).
        Where(Function(x) x IsNot lvi AndAlso x.Tag?.ToString = "p").
        ToList().ForEach(Sub(x)
                             x.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
                             x.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText
                             x.SubItems(x.SubItems.Count - 1).Text = "Done..."
                             x.Tag = "d"
                         End Sub)

    lvi.Tag = "p"
    lvi.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue
    lvi.ForeColor = Color.White
    lvi.SubItems(lvi.SubItems.Count - 1).Text = "Processing..."
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this code. I tried it and it worked.
My only little problem is, the listview is keep refreshing when the process is running

Answer (score 1):

I already solved the problem specially with updating the status and also the flickering problem with using (maybe might help other too)

```
Public Class ffListView
    Inherits ListView

    Public Sub New()
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

and I modified my code with your ideas. althought I did not used your given code but it's really help me a lot to fix my problem.
I just decided instead of displaying the processing and done. I just display the progress

```
 Dim searchItem As String = lblOutputName.Text
                For Each lvi As ListViewItem In LV.Items
                    For Each lvisub As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In lvi.SubItems
                        If lvisub.Text = searchItem Then
                            lvi.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 99, 177)
                            lvi.ForeColor = Color.White
                            lvi.Text = String.Format("{0:F}", Progress).ToString & "%"

                            If lvi.Text = "100.00%" Then
                                lvi.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(4, 117, 24)
                                lvi.ForeColor = Color.White
                            End If
                            If abort Then
                                lvi.BackColor = Color.DarkRed
                                lvi.ForeColor = Color.White
                            End If
                            Exit For

                        End If

                    Next
                Next
```

[image: My updated version]